# Entity Framework inserting null despite providing value

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use entity framework to save data to an SQL Server table. I am using the DB first approach. However I keep on getting this error that `user_id` is null, yet I have assigned it in the code:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'user_id', table 'dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
> The statement has been terminated.

Here is my code:

```
    public ActionResult SaveUser(User user)
    {
        using (DBEntities entities = new DBEntities())
        {
            int maxUserId = entities.Users
                .Select(u => u.user_id)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                .Max();

            user.user_id = maxUserId + 1;

            entities.Users.Add(user);                
            entities.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
        }
    }
```

The user class:

```
public partial class User
{  
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Captured { get; set; }       
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Even if this worked, this is not a correct approach to getting a unique ID. This is not safe if multiple requests arrive at roughly the same time. Use an `IDENTITY` column or an explicit `SEQUENCE` on the server end.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no users, the user_id will return null, and therefore the new user cannot be inserted. This is not the correct way to get a unique ID. See the comment from @Jeroen Mostert

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class User
{  
[Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Captured { get; set; }       
}


public ActionResult SaveUser(User user)
    {
        using (DBEntities entities = new DBEntities())
        { // dont set Id    
            entities.Users.Add(user);                
            entities.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
        }
    }
```